# How to edit a cell in a CSV file

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk, text-processing

I am looking for a shell script to modify data in cell (not all cells in column) in a *CSV* file. I have this command:

```
awk -v r=2 -v c=1 -v val=xxx -F, \
    'BEGIN{OFS=";"}; NR != r; NR == r {$c = val; print}' data.csv
```

input:

```
1995; 1999; 1857; 1349;
1999; 2000; 1824; 1875;
1923; 1324; 1343; 1432;
```

output:

```
1995; 1999; 1857; 1349;
1999; xxx; 1824; 1875;
1923; 1324; 1343; 1432;
```

I need to modify *B2* cell and put inside *xxx* string instead *2000*. This command doesn't work, could anybody help me?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide some input and expected output data.

Answer (score 3):

`-F,` is setting the `FS` to `,` when your actual `FS` is `;`. Do this:

```
awk -v r=2 -v c=2 -v val='xxx' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==r{$c=val} 1' data.csv
```

or if every semi-colon really is followed by a blank char like in your posted sample input/output:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="; "}
```

or if blanks after each `;` are optional:

```
BEGIN{FS="; ?"; OFS="; "}
```

or:

```
BEGIN{FS="; *"; OFS="; "}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *GNU* `sed`, the *row* is the leading *2*, and the *column* is the final *2*, (*i.e.* cell *B2* is *row 2*,*column 2*):

```
sed '2s/\(\S\+\);/xxx;/2' data.csv
```

Output:

```
1995; 1999; 1857; 1349;
1999; xxx; 1824; 1875;
1923; 1324; 1343; 1432;
```

---

Note: the OP uses *row 2, column 2* for input, but the answer might be clearer for learners if the row and column numbers were not the same.  Here's a little wrapper function for better contrast:

```
# Usage: xxx row column filename
#        xxx row column < filename
xxx() { sed "$1"'s/\(\S\+\);/xxx;/'"$2" "${3:-/dev/stdin}" ; }
```

Test:

```
xxx 2 2 data.csv
```

Output:

```
1995; 1999; 1857; 1349;
1999; xxx; 1824; 1875;
1923; 1324; 1343; 1432;
```

With different numbers:

```
xxx 1 3 data.csv
```

Output:

```
1995; 1999; xxx; 1349;
1999; 2000; 1824; 1875;
1923; 1324; 1343; 1432;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --nidx --fs ";" clean-whitespace then put 'if ($[[[2]]] == 2000 && NR ==2) {$[[[2]]] = "xxx"}' input.txt
```

you will have

```
1995;1999;1857;1349;
1999;xxx;1824;1875;
1923;1324;1343;1432;
```